# ABCD is a parallelogram with side AB=12 cm. Its diagonal AC and BD are of lengths 20 cm and 16 cm respectively. Find the area of parallelogram ABCD.

Tags: geometry

> ABCD is a parallelogram with side AB=12 cm. Its diagonal AC and BD are of lengths 20 cm and 16 cm respectively. Find the area of parallelogram ABCD.

I tried,

Area of parallelogram$=\frac 12 \cdot \text{product of diagonals}
                     =\frac 12\cdot 20\cdot 16$

But, this is not matching the answer at the back of the book.

Comment: This: *Area of parallelogram=1/2*product of diagonals* is wrong. A rectangle is a special case of a parallelogram, so the equation should apply to it, too, right? But if you take a rectangle 1 by 100, its diagonals are about 100, so the expression above gives area about 5000, while it actually is 100...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a parallelogram of diagonals $p$ and $q$ the area is actually given by
$$A=\frac{pq}{2}\sin(\theta)$$ 
given that $\theta$ is the angle between the diagonals. The formula you used is for a *rhombus* which is a special case of the parallelogram wherein all the four sides are equal.

**Hint.** To solve this problem you can see [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/ParallelogramArea.svg) that a parallelogram can be 'formed' into a rectangle with the same area. From this we can gather the side length $BC$ and use the formula for a rectangle, namely $A=b\times h.$

Comment: I am not quite familiar with logarithms. Is there any other method to solve the problem.

Comment: There were no references to logarithms in my answer.

Comment: What does that sine-theta means?

Comment: That the the trigonometric sine function. Are you not familiar with trigonometry?

Comment: Oh sorry! It's not logarithms, I am not familiar with trigonometry.

Comment: For problems in geometry, such as this one, you will absolutely, definitely, really badly, need to know trigonometry.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Once I complete trigonometry chapter, I will attempt this question.

Comment: @J.Finnegan You're right, for most problems in geometry one needs trigonometry, but there are some exceptions. Like this one.

Comment: That is very true. But you did suggest using law of cosines. Trig makes life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the J.Finnegan answer, but add a [Law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to it, and when you have a cosine of the angle between diagonals use [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) to obtain its sine.

**EDIT**
You can also use a [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to calculate an area of a triangle with sides 12, 10 and 8 cm (hope you know *which* triangle it is), then find its height. The height doubled becomes a height of the whole parallelogram, so you can easily make a final step.

Answer (score 0):

The key fact here is that the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other. Therefore, a paralellogram is divided into four triangles of equal area by its diagonals.

Let $O$ be the intersection of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$. Then,
$$(ABCD)=4(ABO).$$
Here the sides of $ABO$ are $12,\frac{20}2=10,\frac{16}2=8.$ It follows from Heron's formula that $(ABO)=15\sqrt 7$ and $(ABCD)=60\sqrt7$.

Answer (score -1):

$$(12 + x)^2 + h^2 = 20^2$$
$$(12 - x)^2 + h^2 = 16^2$$

$$x = 3 ∧ h = 5·\sqrt7$$

$$A = 12·5·\sqrt7 = 60·\sqrt7 ≈ 158.7$$

Comment: Use latex, please.